# How do I get Chrome to remember the passwords?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1

I go to a work website (inside the company's firewall).  I connect to my work network via VPN.  I am greeted with this popup.

[image]

I enter user name and password and everything is fine.  However, if I quit Chrome and try again, it will ask me for authentication again.

Is there anyway to make Chrome remember the username and password?

Comment: Have you tried this: `chrome://settings/` and then **Show advanced settings** , scroll to **Passwords and forms** and then mark **Offer to save your Web Passwords**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Google Chrome and go to settings and select "Show advanced options" and go to Passwords and Forms there Check that option "offer to save your web password" and then go to manage Passwords in it remove the sites in the never saved tab This will allow you to save password for that sites...

Comment: This is how it SHOULD work yes!